# Skypeで通話相手のIPアドレスを取得する方法

Tags: network

スカイプを動かした状態で、ワイヤーシャーク（パケット解析ソフト）を使ってスカイプ通信相手側のIPアドレスを取得するテストを行いました。
フィルターには「ip.src=192.168.0.hoge and udp.srcport == (Skype受信ポート)」
を指定しましたが、IPアドレスを検出する事は出来ませんでした。
ルーターのグローバルIP（と思われるアドレス）は取得していました。
何か間違ってる点があるのでしょうか？

環境はワイヤーシャークを動作させているクライアントはMAC(10.11.4)通信相手は同一ローカルネット内のWindowsマシンと外部ネットワークのWindowsマシンです。
ネットワークはCATVからルーターモデムを通してローカルネットワーク上のパソコンでスカイプが動いてます。
ご教示お願いします

Answer (score 1):

Skypeの通信はよく分かってませんが、ルーターがNATしているのでしょうからプライベートIPは見えないと思います。